# How to refactor common logic from types in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a bunch of type which holds  time series data.
Like, a list of journal with dates ,a bank statement with list of transactions.
I want to make a `class` to annotate these type `slice-able` like in Python slice `[:]`

that would create a nightmare to implement `TsList` to all the types because:
there are lots of `filter` ... `txns` in common . Is there any way to factor out this common logic ?

```
data BoundDate = Include Date
               | Exclude Date

class TsList a where
  subByRange :: a -> Maybe BoundDate -> Maybe BoundDate -> a

--- with Statement type 
instance TsList Statement where
  subByRange s@(Statement txns) Nothing Nothing = s
  subByRange s@(Statement txns) Nothing (Just ed) = 
    case ed of 
       Include d -> Statement $ filter ( x -> x <= d ) txns
       Exclude d -> Statement $ filter ( x -> x < d ) txns
  subByRange s@(Statement txns) (Just sd) Nothing =
    case sd of 
       Include d -> Statement $ filter ( x -> x => d ) txns
       Exclude d -> Statement $ filter ( x -> x > d ) txns
  subByRange s@(Statement txns) (Just sd) (Just ed) =
       Statement $ subByRange _s Nothing (Just ed)
    where
       _s = Statement $ subByRange s (Just sd) Nothing

--- now with Journal type 
instance TsList Journal where
  subByRange s@(Journal txns) Nothing Nothing = s
  subByRange s@(Journal txns) Nothing (Just ed) = 
    case ed of 
       Include d -> Journal $ filter ( x -> x <= d ) txns
       Exclude d -> Journal $ filter ( x -> x < d ) txns
  subByRange s@(Statement txns) (Just sd) Nothing =
    case sd of 
       Include d -> Journal $ filter ( x -> x => d ) txns
       Exclude d -> Journal $ filter ( x -> x > d ) txns
  subByRange s@(Statement txns) (Just sd) (Just ed) =
       Journal $ subByRange _s Nothing (Just ed)
    where
       _s = Journal $ subByRange s (Just sd) Nothing
```

Comment: Implement the instance for a naked list and then use `DerivingVia`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Or it should work to implement it for `Statement`, and then use `DerivingVia` for the `Journal` instance

Comment: What's different about `Statement` and `Journal` values other than their type? Perhaps a single parameterized type like `data DocumentType = Statement | Journal` and `data Document a = Document DocumentType [a]` would suffice; `instance TsList (Document a)` could simply ignore the document type.

Comment: Maybe consider not having a class at all. Instead have `transactions :: Statement -> [Transaction]` and just write `subByRange (transactions s) x y` at the call-site instead, with `subByRange` a function that only works on lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to implement these functions over just plain old lists and then the class instances are just newtype wrapper/unwrappers.

For instance, you can define:

```hs
subByRangeList :: [Date] -> Maybe BoundDate -> Maybe BoundDate -> [Date]
subByRangeList s Nothing Nothing = s
subByRangeList s Nothing (Just ed) = 
  case ed of 
     Include d -> filter ( x -> x <= d ) s
     Exclude d -> filter ( x -> x < d ) s
subByRangeList s (Just sd) Nothing =
  case sd of 
     Include d -> filter ( x -> x >= d ) s
     Exclude d -> filter ( x -> x > d ) s
subByRangeList s (Just sd) (Just ed) =
     subByRangeList _s Nothing (Just ed)
  where
     _s = subByRangeList s (Just sd) Nothing
```

And then your instances are simply:

```hs
instance TsList Statement where
  subByRange (Statement txns) = Statement $ subByRangeList txns

instance TsList Journal where
  subByRange (Journal txns) = Journal $ subByRangeList txns
```

---

One potential annoyance of this is if you have a bunch of class methods in `TsList` (or a bunch of instances), and you don't want to even have to define each one the same way with the newtype wrapping/unwrapping.  You can make use of `DefaultSignatures` and the `Coercible` type class to write:

```hs
class TsList a where
  subByRange :: a -> Maybe BoundDate -> Maybe BoundDate -> a
  default subByRange :: (Coercible a [Date], Coercible [Date] a) => a -> Maybe BoundDate -> Maybe BoundDate -> a
  subByRange s x y = coerce $ subByRangeList (coerce s) x y

instance TsList Statement
instance TsList Journal
```

Because `Statement` and `Journal` are simply newtype wrappers around `[Date]`, they will be able to use the default version of `subByRange`, so all you need to do is declare that they're instances.

Answer (score 2):

As @FyodorSoikin mentioned in the comments, perhaps the easiest way to do this is to use the GHC language extension [`DerivingVia`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html). To do this, add the following declaration to the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}
```

Now, assuming that your types are defined as `newtype`s, GHC will be able to automatically derive one instance from the other if you tell it so:

```
newtype Statement = Statement [Int]   -- or something like this

instance TsList Statement where
    -- ...as in the question...

newtype Journal = Journal [Int]
    deriving (TsList) via Statement
```

(Note that this only works if both `Statement` and `Journal` are `newtype` wrappers around the same type.)

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want this to work with more sophisticated data types than simple wrappers around `[Date]` you'll need some more advanced tooling. Fortunately, GHC provides some. You can use the [`Data.Data` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Data.html) to handle this more broadly.

First, we'll need a bit of tooling. Many libraries export something equivalent to this function, but it's simple enough that I'll just include it instead pulling in an extra dependency.

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables, GADTs #-}

import Data.Data

-- Apply the function anywhere in the data type where it has the
-- correct type. Don't recurse further when the type matches.
deepMap :: forall a s. (Typeable a, Data s) => (a -> a) -> s -> s
deepMap f = go
  where
    go :: forall x. Data x => x -> x
    go d = case eqT :: Maybe (a :~: x) of
        Just Refl -> f d
        Nothing -> gmapT go d
```

(It's possible to improve that function a lot for performance in edge cases. If you care about that, you should use a version that comes from a library.)

With that functionality available, you can take advantage of the `DefaultSignatures` extension to provide a default implementation in the class that will work for any `Data` instance.

```
{-# Language DefaultSignatures, DeriveDataTypeable #-}

-- whatever, this needed some definition
data Date = Date deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Data)

data BoundDate = Include Date
               | Exclude Date
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Data)

-- factor out the common logic
filterSubRange :: Maybe BoundDate -> Maybe BoundDate -> [Date] -> [Date]
filterSubRange Nothing Nothing txns = txns
filterSubRange  Nothing (Just ed) txns =
    case ed of
       Include d -> filter (<= d) txns
       Exclude d -> filter (< d) txns
filterSubRange (Just sd) Nothing txns =
    case sd of
       Include d -> filter (>= d) txns
       Exclude d -> filter (> d) txns
filterSubRange (Just sd) (Just ed) txns =
    filterSubRange Nothing (Just ed) txns'
  where
    txns' = filterSubRange (Just sd) Nothing txns

-- provide a default implementation that uses filterSubRange on any
-- [Date] the type contains
class TsList a where
    subByRange :: a -> Maybe BoundDate -> Maybe BoundDate -> a

    default subByRange :: Data a => a -> Maybe BoundDate -> Maybe BoundDate -> a
    subByRange s lo hi = deepMap (filterSubRange lo hi) s


-- some definitions containing whatever.
data Statement = Statement (Maybe String) Bool [Date]
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Data)
newtype Journal = Journal [Date]
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Data)

-- empty instances use the default definition
instance TsList Statement
instance TsList Journal
```

As you can see from the definition of `Statement`, this works on more complex data types. It may not do what you want if a type has multiple `[Date]` values inside it - in which case, you can write out the instance by hand. And maybe you can take advantage of the fact that `filterSubRange` is a standalone function in the process.